# multivariate gaussian probability density function python on Mac

Tags: python, scipy, probability-density

I'm unable to use SciPy and its modules for calculating the probability density function of a multivariate Gaussian distribution.  I know that such modules exist, but I'm unable to use them (I can't even import scipy: I get the message: `ImportError: No module named scipy`).

I was wondering if there were any good tool or other way to calculate the pdf of a multivariate Gaussian distribution in python.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is provided by `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf()`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html. You will need to specify the `mean` and `variance-covariance matrix`.

Before that you need to install `scipy` if you have not done so. You can either download a `.dmg` installation package. Or try an 'distribution' such as `Anaconda Python`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.  I've now installed SciPy (I first installed anaconda, and then I also used pip).  After each, I am successfully able to "import scipy" and "import scipy.stats", but when I type "from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal" in my Python code, I encounted the error: "ImportError: cannot import name multivariate_normal".  Do you have any ideas as to how I might be able to gain access to multivariate_normal so I can use the multivariate_normal.pdf() function?

Comment: You need `scipy` version>0.14.0 for this I believe. `Anaconda` is probably shipped with `0.13.3` or whatever the last stable release is. New versions are there: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.14.0b1/. For `Anaconda` you probably has to install it from source.